# can't find my error, xor cipher

Tags: php, objective-c, xor

i have code in objc

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/second.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *data=[self transform:@"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" Key:@"0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945"];
    NSData *requestBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"p=%@",data] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[[UIAlertView  alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:responseString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"log=%@",responseString);


}

- (NSString*) transform:(NSString*)input Key:(NSString*)key
{
    NSMutableString* output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    unsigned int vlen = [input length];
    unsigned int klen = [key length];
    unsigned int v = 0;
    unsigned int k = 0;


    for (v=0; v < vlen; v++) {
        unichar c = [input characterAtIndex:v] ^ [key characterAtIndex:k];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c]];

        k = (++k < klen ? k : 0);
    }

    NSString* final = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:output] autorelease];
    [output release];
    return final;
}
```

and decrypt at php

```
$res="";
$key="0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945";
$k=0;
if ($_POST['p']){


        $vlen = strlen($_POST['p']);
        $klen = strlen($key);
        $v = 0;
        $k = 0;

        for ($v=0; $v < $vlen; $v++) {
            $c = $_POST['p'][$v] ^ $key[$k];
            $res=$res.$c;
            $k = (++$k < $klen ? $k : 0);
        }

    echo $res;
    }
```

but when i check it the result is

> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcv>d=1"+dssstcn|e~dn1;9?nve,e9;upg('%&5nqfyelfdnfll$+f'6icr&oh#'(s4>vas6;aclkl|}brg86tp4#xz!hb!2"b;6njk>'~hpbnktvaw""pn>!mp0gj9lkj`~,3|i6=

however i send the message

> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

please, help me to find my error.

Comment: found my problem, it was here $k = (++$k < $klen ? $k : 0); i rewrite it to simple if not ternary

Answer (score 1):

At position 50, you XOR character "b" from your string with character "b" from your key, which results in a [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). This is likely being interpreted as a control character and being discarded.

You use the word "cipher"; however, the method you are employing is not in any way secure. Perhaps you could give more detail as to what you're trying to achieve here. Is there any reason you've opted not to use SSL for encryption?

Comment: It is a cipher.  It's just not considered secure any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't xor two unichars and expect the result to be a valid unichar.  This is a general problem with your algorithm which first goes wrong at character 50 as jnic says. You need to first convert the NSString and the key to an NSData using `-dataWithEncoding:` Then you do the encryption.  Then you need to send the binary data to your PHP server.  The PHP server needs to reverse all the steps in the Objective-C program.